# assigning variables in a file to an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing a list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669571/printing-a-list-in-java)

I have different variables in a file that I need to assign to different variable arrays.  Here is what is in the file:

```
Lee Keith Austin Kacie Jason Sherri     Jordan     Corey Reginald Brian Taray 
Christopher Randy Henry Jeremy Robert    Joshua   Robert   Eileen 
Cassandra Albert Russell   Ethan   Cameron Tyler Alex Kentrell  rederic
10 20 100 80 25 35 15 10 45 55 200 300 110 120 111 7 27 97 17 37 
21 91 81 71 16 23 33 45
A  b  c w e r t q I u y b G J K S A p o m b v x K F s q w
11.5 29.9 100  200 115.1 33.3 44.4 99.9 100.75 12.2 13.1 20.3 55.5 77.7
12.1 7.1  8.2   9.9   100.1  22.2  66.6 9.9  1.25     3.75   19.9  3.321  45.54 88.8
```

And here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prog5Methods{
public Prog5Methods(){
}
    public void ReadFromFile(Scanner input, String [] names, int [] numbers, char [] letters, double [] num2){
        System.out.println("\nReading from a file...\n");
        System.out.println("\nDONE\n");
        int r = 0;
            while(input.hasNext()){
                names[r] = input.next();
                numbers[r] = input.nextInt();
                letters[r] = input.next().charAt(0);
                num2[r] = input.nextDouble();
                r++;
        }
} // end of readFromFile
```

I am getting an IndexOutOfBounds exception every time.  How can I assign these types to these arrays?

Comment: Your file and your code don't seem to match at all. Your code suggests that you will have a name then an int, then a letter, then a double, then repeat until all gone. Your file shows all names grouped together, all ints, all char, all doubles, etc... I think you'd better fix this. Also do you know in advance how many of each are present?

Comment: For homework questions, you should tag them as such.

Comment: OK, so you've got 28 items of each type. Are you using 28 as the number of array items to allocate for each array?  Consider doing this, and then filling each array one at a time with the type order as presented in the data file.

Comment: OP started second thread for the same question -  [Printing a list in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669571/printing-a-list-in-java) and here is answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669571/printing-a-list-in-java/7669786#7669786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the arrays passed into the function have the right length set.   If you are getting `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, you are probably not initializing the arrays based on whats in the file.

Another option is to use a `List`, which has no size restriction, and then to convert the lists into  arrays.  See [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) for an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add more items to your array than your array has space for, try using a List like [java.util.ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Also the file shows a list of names, then a list of numbers, then a list of letters, then a list of decimals, but in your code, you read in a name, then a number, then a letter, then a double.

Try something like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

public class Prog5Methods{
    public void foo(String filename){
        ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Character> chars=new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Double> dubs=new ArrayList<Double>();
        ReadFromFile(new Scanner(new File(filename)),names,ints,chars,dubs);
    }
    public void ReadFromFile(Scanner input, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> numbers, ArrayList<Character> letters, ArrayList<Double> num2){
        System.out.println("\nReading from a file...\n");
        while(input.hasNext()&&!input.hasNextInt()){
            names.add(input.next());
        }
        while(input.hasNextInt()){
            numbers.add(input.nextInt());
        }
        while(input.hasNext()&&!input.hasNextDouble()){
            letters.add(input.next().charAt(0));
        }
        while(input.hasNextDouble()){
            num2.add(input.nextDouble());
        }
        System.out.println("\nDONE\n");
    }
    public String[] convertToArray(ArrayList<String> arr){
        String[] ans=new String[arr.size()];
        arr.toArray(ans);
        return ans;
    }
}
```